# How to create a for loop, which returns True if the list's numbers are in order and otherwise False?

Tags: python

I have attempted to write a function which loops over items in a list and returns True if the item is larger than the previous item in the list, and False if not, but it doesn't seem to work properly. Can anyone point me towards my error.

```
def inc_fun(x):
  for i in range(len(x)):
    for xi in x:
      if x[i] > x[i-1]:
        return True
      else:
        return False

inc_fun([1,2,3,7,9])
```

Returns: False

This should be true, if I run:

```
inc_fun([1,5,3,2,9])
```

This also returns false.

I appreciate any help :)

Comment: Which item is larger than any previous item in the list? You are returning on first check so the function exits. There is not going to be any more checks than the first one. Also, you are iterating needlessly twice through the list. The second for loop is redundant, you never do anything with `xi` variable.

Comment: So essentially you want to check if the numbers are in order from smallest to largest?

Comment: The first `xi` will return either `True` or `False`. No other values of `xi` will be evaluated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you actually want to check if the numbers in the list are in order from the smallest to the largest. You can achieve this easily with:

```
def inc_fun(x):
    return x == sorted(x)
```

There really is very little point in using anything else when the lists are some hundred or thousand elements long, since this is the most readable and easy to understand way. But if you insist on being able to do this in linear time, you can use:

```
def inc_fun(x):
    for i in range(len(x) - 1):
        if x[i] > x[i + 1]:
            return False
    return True
```

Or the same in one line:

```
def inc_fun(x):
    return all(x[i] <= x[i + 1] for i in range(len(x) - 1))
```

---

Your existing code has two big problems:

```
def inc_fun(x):
  for i in range(len(x)):
    # Using nested loops with a 1d list doesn't make much sense.
    for xi in x:
      # You return immediately after the first element,
      # so you never check more than the first pair.
      if x[i] > x[i-1]:
        return True
      else:
        return False
```

Comment: Thanks, I know there are simpler ways of doing it, but I was trying to get it to work using a loop. Thanks for the commented code, that really helps my understanding. Out of interest, is there a way to do it by using a range of x from 1:x (avoiding the i-1 error on x[0]) so it can be done with < x[i-1] ?

Comment: @ScientistStats You could start your range from `1` : `def inc_fun(x):
    for i in range(1, len(x)):
        if x[i] > x[i - 1]:
            return False
    return True`

Answer (score 1):

For the first evaluation (i=0) of x[i-1], you get x[-1], which is equal to 9.

Answer (score 1):

Your index `i` when at 0 is a problem.

Indeed when you do `if x[i] > x[i-1]` your are looking for `x[0]` and `x[-1]` and in python `x[-1]` is the last item of a list. So you are checking if 1 > 9 which is `False`

The other problem in your function is that you don't check the entire list but you are checking only once since you quit your function with `return`